# Couldn't install tensorflow on windows

Tags: tensorflow, windows-7, python-3.6

While installing tensorflow on my windows, the following error message is displayed.Please help me in fixing it. 
[open this image for viewing the error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ZBay.png)

Comment: Do you have the 64-bit version of Python installed?  Or 32-bit?  `tensorflow` requires 64-bit Python 3.

Comment: I have 32 bit version of python installed. what should I do now?

Comment: Uninstall Python and reinstall it.  Make sure you install Python 64-bit this time.

Answer (score 0):

If one of the following versions of Python is not installed on your machine, install it now:

- Python 3.5.x 64-bit from python.org
- Python 3.6.x 64-bit from python.org

TensorFlow supports Python 3.5.x and 3.6.x on Windows. Note that Python 3 comes with the pip3 package manager, which is the program you'll use to install TensorFlow.

To install TensorFlow, start a terminal. Then issue the appropriate pip3 install command in that terminal. To install the CPU-only version of TensorFlow, enter the following command:

`C:\> pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow`

To install the GPU version of TensorFlow, enter the following command:

`C:\> pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow-gpu`